# Webcomponent Tester - How to assert a function not to be called?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, sinon-chai, web-component-tester

Using Polymer 1.* and webcomponent tester...

I have `spy(alert, 'open')` and `expect(alert.open).to.have.not.been.called;`. How can I assert a function is not called? Right now this. If I inverse it with  `expect(alert.open).to.have.been.called;`, it also fails.

I tried `.calledCount(0)` and it defaults to `has not been called` which fails.

The spy is good, it's just complaining ether way that it is not asserted and test fails.

Answer (score 1):

You should expect on the spy itself

```
const myElement = fixture('my-element');
const openSpy = sinon.spy(myElement, 'open');
//myElement.doSomethingThatShouldNotTriggerOpen();
openSpy.should.have.callCount(0);
```